How to Configure Keycloak to Validate a Base64 Client Certificate from "WL-Proxy-Client-Cert" Header of REST request?
I have a scenario where I need to authenticate and validate a Base64-encoded client certificate that is included in the HTTP headers under the name "WL-Proxy-Client-Cert". I am using Keycloak for authentication and would like to set it up to perform this certificate validation.
Could someone please provide detailed steps or guidance on how to configure Keycloak for this purpose? Specifically, I need to know:
How to configure Keycloak to extract and validate the client certificate from the "WL-Proxy-Client-Cert" header.
Any specific settings or configurations required within Keycloak to handle Base64-encoded client certificates.
Whether any additional Keycloak plugins or extensions are needed to enable this functionality.
I appreciate any insights or examples that can help achieve this integration between Keycloak and the client certificate provided in the HTTP header.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
I have tried to implement using official Keyclock document but not able to implement it.
(https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_x509)
